# Drawing Circle in Python isn't in correct location

Tags: python, pygame, range, geometry

I am making a tower defense game, and for the range of the towers I'm making a circle with the tower being it's central point.  Although, when I draw a circle using pygame.draw.rect(), it seems to be in a completely different location.  Here is the code for it.

Variables :

```
Radius = 50
Center_X = 100
Center_Y = 100
```

For checking if enemies are in range of the circle :

```
for Enemy in Enemies:
    if ((Enemy['Rect'].left + 10) - Center_X)^2 + ((Enemy['Rect'].top + (35/2)) Center_Y)^2 < Radius^2:
        print(1)
```

For drawing the circle :

```
pygame.draw.circle(Window, Black, (Center_X, Center_Y), Radius, 0)
```

Comment: The drawn circle seems to be in a completely different location in comparison to what?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want and what you get?

Comment: In comparison to the circle that I have made using the equation.

It seems that the equation will detect an enemy even if the enemy isn't in the drawn circle.  It will print '1' into the console even if the enemy isn't touching the drawn circle.

Comment: Maybe you have wrong data in equation. Better `print` x,y both elements and compare. Why do you get `.left + 10` and `.top + (35/2)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pygame.Rect()` to keep sprites positon.

```
Center_X = 100
Center_Y = 100

positon = pygame.Rect() 
positon.centerx = Center_X
positon.centery = Center_Y
```

and now you can draw it

```
pygame.draw.circle(Window, Black, position.center, Radius, 0)
```

and you can use `pygame.Rect()` with [collision detection](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)

See more in PyGame Docs: [pygame.Rect()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

You can use [pygame.Sprite()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) to have [circle collision detection](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the exponentiation operator is `**`, not  `^`, that is a [bitwise XOR operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

```
2^2
0
32^1
33
```

Instead:

```
2**2
4
32**1
32
```

So:

```
if ((Enemy['Rect'].left + 10) - Center_X) ** 2 + ((Enemy['Rect'].top + (35/2)) - Center_Y)**2 < Radius**2:
```